# How closure is working in grails in GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, groovyshell

I was reading grails criteria API , I find the following code in grails API [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html)

```
     def c = Account.createCriteria()
     def results = c {
         projections {
             groupProperty("branch")
         }
         like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
         and {
             between("balance", 500, 1000)
             eq("branch", "London")
         }
         maxResults(10)
         order("holderLastName", "desc")
     }
```

my question is calling Account.createCriteria() will gives you grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder object but when say "c { ....}" , I know colsure is getting called but the object we have is HibernateCriteriaBuilder object not the Closure object , then how the closure is getting called .

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking when you say "then how its working". What problem are you encountering or trying to solve?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I edited my question . I want to know how closure is getting called when we have HibernateCriteriaBuilder object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [in the API](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html) this wraps the Hibernate Criteria API in a builder. [Builders](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/How+Builders+Work) are used in Groovy to create Domain Specific Languages (DSLs) such as the GORM DSL.

Comment: Thanks . But the builders link you provided doesn't have full documentation

Comment: There is no such thing as full documentation for builders since it's a complex topic that isn't specific to Groovy as a language. For instance: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Builders is the closest to "full documentation" provided by Groovy. I recommend you do some research on the topic using Google.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you intended to do something like c.list { ... } instead of c { ... }?  Those are fundamentally different.  The former is invoking the list method and passing a Closure as an argument.  The latter is attempting to invoke the "call" method and pass a Closure as an argument.